# ERRO - Pegar XElement C#

Tags: c#, xml, nfe

Olá. Estou tentando pegar um Node de um xml NFe poderem esta aparecendo o erro da imagem. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No inicio da classe foi criado uma variável `private XDocument xDoc;` O arquivo xml está dentro da pasta do debug.

Mesmo colocando assim aparece o mesmo Erro:

```
XElement _xDetModelo = new XElement(xDoc.Element("nfeProc").Element("NFe").Element("infNFe").Element("det"));
```

Abaixo parte do código do XML que estou tentando pegar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">
    <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
        <infNFe Id="NFeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" versao="3.10">
            <ide>
                    ...
            </ide>
            <emit>
                    ...
            </emit>
            <dest>
                    ...
            </dest>
            <det nItem="1">
                <prod>
                    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O arquivo possui `namespace`, e na hora da busca dos ***elementos*** ele precisa ser informado:

```
XNamespace nameSpace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe";
string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("doc.xml");

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement element = xDoc.Element(nameSpace + "nfeProc")
          .Element(nameSpace + "NFe")
          .Element(nameSpace + "infNFe")
          .Element(nameSpace + "det");
```

Exemplo no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998849/6797930), demonstra isso.

***Editado:***

```
Func<string, XName> item = delegate(string value)
{
    XNamespace nameSpace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe";
    return nameSpace + value;
};


string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("doc.xml");

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);           

var element = from el in xDoc.Element(item("nfeProc"))
        .Element(item("NFe"))
        .Element(item("infNFe"))
        .Element(item("det"));
```

Comment: Virgilio Novic Obrigado, sua solução funcionou. Só uma duvida. tem como deixar o nameSpace "Universal" para a minha variavel xDoc? assim não teria que ficar colocando nameSpace + "...".

Comment: @LuisMedeiros, nada ... eu também tinha procurado antes isso, talvez isso aconteça porque pode ter vários `namespace` em cada nó! O que pode ser feito uma classe com funções `static` para resolver isso. mas, não sei se isso seria bom...

Comment: @LuisMedeiros eu fiz uma edição e coloque uma função anonima para auxiliar ...

Answer (score 3):

Apesar de você já ter resolvido com a resposta do colega Virgilio Novic vou mostrar outra forma de fazer isto, você pode criar as classes referente a NFe.

Talvez seja útil para você ou outra pessoa que estiver lendo.

Existe um aplicativo que se chama `xsd.exe`. Resumindo grosseiramente, ele pega o schema e lhe devolve uma classe.

Você deve baixas os schemas da NFe e salva-los em alguma pasta.

Faça o seguinte como na imagem abaixo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logicamente substitua o caminho de acordo onde você salvou o schema da NFe.

Dentro da pasta do `xsd.exe` ele vai criar um arquivo `.cs` como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apos isso você adiciona a classe no seu projeto, você pode usar a NFe como se fosse um objeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Complementando:

Você pode colocar este bloco de código dentro de um `try\catch`, assim caso o xml não seja válido, será gerada uma exceção. Como você gerou a classe a partir do schema, somente serão deserializados os xml's que forem válidos, isso lhe poupará de muita dor de cabeça.